How to version job definitions (AWS Batch on Fargate)
I have a CDK for batch to run jobs using Fargate compute environments. In my CI/CD pushes to the source code for the container are subject to versioning issues.
I’ll push a code change yet an outdated container will be served. My naive fix was to add a a date string to the job definition name, however this does not meet character requirements.
So I’d like to know, what is the appropriate way to ensure proper versioning such that an outdated container is not bulled by batch when a job is popped from the queue?

Two things may be going on:
1. Container caching by ECS.
You can change the behavior of ECS to always pull a container by setting the ECS_IMAGE_PULL_BEHAVIOR=always in a launch template. Here is example user data for doing so (based on an example in the AWS Batch documentation)
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/launch-template-examples.html#example-override-default-amazon-ecs-container-agent-configuration
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==MYBOUNDARY=="

--==MYBOUNDARY==
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"

#!/bin/bash
echo "ECS_IMAGE_PULL_BEHAVIOR=always" >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config

--==MYBOUNDARY==--

2. Batch job definition container image tags
Batch job definitions leverage the container's specific tag to pull a  container, not the checksum. I.e. using latest or another tag would get whatever version of the container is tagged as such. (See note above about container caching).
You cannot override a job definition's image, so if you are using specific container tags, you will need to register a new job definition for that container version.
Note: If you are leveraging Batch on an EKS cluster, you can override the container image when you submit the job. This answer is assuming ECS.
